# Customize Django admin changelist page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

In the django-admin model changelist page I want to interact with other models also.I mean,

I have the three models

```
  1.Keywords

        contains name field

  2.Category
        contains category_name field

  3.Keyword Category Relation
        Category is ForeignKey and Keyword is Many to many field
```

In my Keyword model changelist.html page I need to customize ,The changes will be

```
There should be a dropdown box which lists all category model objects
```

If i select some keywords and also selecting the particular category from the drop down,when hitting the save button The Keywords and catogories need to be updated in another model

How it should be proceed? How it is supposed to do? suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You can override save_model and save_formset functions. Example cases from my own code (admin.py):

```
class SubtaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SubtaskAdminForm
    list_display = ('id', 'task', 'date_created', 'author', 'status', 'is_reclamation')
    list_filter = ('date_created', 'status', 'is_reclamation')
    actions = [change_subtask_status_to_new, change_subtask_status_to_open, change_subtask_status_to_ready]
    fields = ('order', 'task', 'tags', 'amount', 'is_reclamation', 'status')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            obj.author = employee
        obj.save()
        super(SubtaskAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

...

```
class MaintenanceOrderLineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...
        def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
                instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=request.user.id)
                for instance in instances:
                    if isinstance(instance, Subtask): 
                        instance.author = employee
                        instance.save()
```